# Unable to install WineHQ Stable (You have held broken packages)

Tags: software-installation, package-management, wine, elementary-os

I wanted to install Wine in Elementaryos Hera and followed this [site](https://linuxconfig.org/install-wine-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux). The only mistake which I did was, I installed wine from Ubuntu Repositories then followed by trying to install wine from official wine repositories. Then, I installed wineHQ stable using the command `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable` Because I installed wine twice, it didn't work as it should. So I went to the terminal and used the command `dpkg --list` to see what wine based software are installed and uninstalled them using the command `sudo apt-get --purge remove program` I literally uninstalled everything that had **wine** in its name. Now, I reinstalled Wine from official repositories and then added the key for WineHQ Stable and then tried installing it using the first command mentioned above. But I received this message

```
thenotorious@T430:~$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable 
[sudo] password for thenotorious: 
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible 
situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not 
yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to 
resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:   
winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.1~bionic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I fix this up? Someone help me out. I've already searched how to remove broken packages, but just couldn't find the package which I should Delete because I already uninstalled and possibly deleted every folder of wine, and also searched forums regarding not being able to install wineHQ stable due to broken packages, but nothing really helped.

Comment: First try `sudo apt --fix-broken install`.  Then try to manually install the package which is not met (i.e. `wine-stable`)

Comment: It is likely to be you can't install or, update anything. So, visit [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/646485/449077)

Comment: did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

First Uninstall Wine

- may remove the PPA by launching Software & Updates utility and
  navigating to Other Software tab.
  [image]

To remove wine 6.0, run command in terminal:

```
sudo apt remove --auto-remove winehq-stable
```

Install wine Again (Run following Commands)

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

wget -O - https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main' (only Ubuntu 20.04)

sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ groovy main' (only Ubuntu 20.10)

sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main' (only Ubuntu 18.04)

sudo apt update && sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find `winehq-stable` in official repositories. It looks like it's from a ppa or you are installing it from wine.org.

It's having a problem finding `wine-stable`.  I found that it does exist in the [official bionic repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/wine-stable).  `wine-stable` is in the `universe` section.

The `universe` section is for packages which are not supported by the ubuntu core team.  It is not enabled by default on systems. Check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`.  If you don't see something like what's below, then go ahead and add it (change the URL to match the mirror used by your other entries).

```
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
```

Once you've added that, go ahead and `apt update`, then try again.  If you get the problem again, try `apt --fix-broken install`.