# Debian 10 - Broken MariaDB update - system upgrade problems

Tags: debian, mariadb

My system has a broken MariaDb update going from 10.3 to 10.4. MariaDb does still work fine, but now I am having system upgrade issues. I have tried looking online for solutions but can't seem to find anything. Problem:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade               
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  mariadb-server-10.3 : Depends: mariadb-client-10.3 (>= 1:10.3.28+maria~buster) but 1:10.3.27-0+deb10u1 is installed
  mariadb-server-core-10.3 : Breaks: mariadb-client-10.3 (< 1:10.3.28+maria~buster) but 1:10.3.27-0+deb10u1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

While I try to fix-broken :

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libconfig-inifiles-perl libsnappy1v5
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mariadb-client-10.3 mariadb-client-core-10.3
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mariadb-client-10.3 mariadb-client-core-10.3
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,868 kB of archives.
After this operation, 19.6 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Reading changelogs... Done
dpkg: regarding .../mariadb-client-core-10.3_1%3a10.3.28+maria~buster_amd64.deb containing mariadb-client-core-10.3:
 mariadb-client-10.3 conflicts with mysql-client-core-5.5
  mariadb-client-core-10.3 provides mysql-client-core-5.5 and is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-core-10.3_1%3a10.3.28+maria~buster_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 conflicting packages - not installing mariadb-client-core-10.3
dpkg: regarding .../mariadb-client-10.3_1%3a10.3.28+maria~buster_amd64.deb containing mariadb-client-10.3:
 mariadb-client-core-10.3 conflicts with mysql-client-5.5
  mariadb-client-10.3 provides mysql-client-5.5 and is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-10.3_1%3a10.3.28+maria~buster_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 conflicting packages - not installing mariadb-client-10.3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-core-10.3_1%3a10.3.28+maria~buster_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-10.3_1%3a10.3.28+maria~buster_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Are there multiple packages installed? Any ideas?

---

edit: adding more info

Please edit your post to show the contents of your /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
deb [arch=arm64,ppc64el,amd64] http://mariadb.mirror.globo.tech/repo/10.3/debian buster main
# deb-src [arch=arm64,ppc64el,amd64] http://mariadb.mirror.globo.tech/repo/10.3/debian buster main
deb [arch=arm64,ppc64el,amd64] http://mariadb.mirror.globo.tech/repo/10.4/debian buster main
# deb-src [arch=arm64,ppc64el,amd64] http://mariadb.mirror.globo.tech/repo/10.4/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
```

and any *.list files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d:
ondrej-ubuntu-php-impish.list  php7.list

Comment: "mariadb-client-10.3 conflicts with mysql-client-core-5.5" Have you looked in to that? (You cannot have both installed--MariaDB takes over the role, and binaries, of MySQL. It's fully backwards compatible, so you won't lose MySQL functionality.)

Comment: Do yo use MariaDB packages from MariaDB repo or Debian? I think you use MariaDB's repo. If you sort out mysql client confict, as C. M. noted, and still have problems, you could try to remove MariaDB repo and install/update using Debian repo packages. Currently, the latter provides MariaDB version 10.3.27-0+deb10u1 on Debian 10.9 Buster.

Comment: Explaining in the question how the problem initially happened often helps solving it (eg: use of `dpkg -i` instead of `apt-get install`?)

Comment: @Krackout I should uninstall mysql?

Comment: @A.B I set up the server over a year ago following a tutorial that had me install MariaDB on a fresh Debian 10. Now I am trying to update MariaDb.

Comment: @C.M. I tried sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove mysql-server-core
and I got the same first error message as above:  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server-10.3 : Depends: mariadb-client-10.3 (>= 1:10.3.28+maria~buster) but 1:10.3.27-0+deb10u1 is to be installed
 mariadb-server-core-10.3 : Breaks: mariadb-client-10.3 (< 1:10.3.28+maria~buster) but 1:10.3.27-0+deb10u1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Should I force it? sudo apt-get --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mysql-server-core

Comment: Is it possible to force cancel the failed installation? I tried clean and auto clean but it did not help.

Comment: For now, I suggest not trying anything that may break your system even more. Identify the exact problem before applying any force, so you know when you truly need to force it. Please edit your post to show the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and any *.list files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, so we can see what your repository working-set is like.

Comment: Since you are using a MariaDB repository, if you followed instructions there: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-deb-files/#updating-the-mariadb-apt-repository-to-a-new-major-release you should probably file a bug to MariaDB about this anyway.

Comment: Some suggestions while unistalling: You should use `apt-get remove` not `purge`, in order to retain config files, since you'll re-install eventually; start removing the conflicting package, apparently mariadb-client. If it fails, try to remove all in one pass using wildcards: `sudo apt remove mariadb*` so that everything regarding mariadb is removed. Then clean up your `sources.list.d` and re-install. If you are interested in the most stable setup, but not cutting edge features, remove mariadb repo and install it from Debian repo. You should also take a backup of all your data prior.

Comment: @C.M. I have added the information that you requested. What do you think I should do ?

Comment: @pmichaels: Is here anything in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`? Note the '.d' added to the end, indicating that it's a directory for additional \*.list files for `apt` repositories. It is usually better to keep `/etc/apt/sources.list` only listing the default Debian repos, and add \*.list files in to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, such as a file "mariadb.list' which would only contain mariadb repos. This way, you can rename it like 'mariasb.list.disabled' to disable the repo instead of deleting it entirely, without affecting your other repos.

Comment: As for what else to do.. I am not certain yet. I am trying to help identify the problem first... We cannot fix a problem when we do not know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I had earlier face the problem also in Kali. If `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` isn't empty than "remove" everything inside the directory. **It is better to rename those files rather than removing**. You should try following command.

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you keep face the issue than try

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you again face the problem than run as a root user(`sudo su`)

```
sudo -s
apt --fix-broken install
apt upgrade
```

Comment: I tried this and I still have the same output as originally.

Comment: Please do not suggest removal of of any system-critical files. If anything, suggest renaming the files/directories, so they can be restored if it was not helpful. (Also, it should be `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, not "sources.d".)

Comment: @C.M. Oh yeah that's `sources.list.d` not `sources.d` I just wrote as [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/645565/467213) I couldn't check cause, I am not using Debian Based Distro now..

Comment: @Istiak: Please edit your answer to correct that. And also, please do as I suggested and advise them to rename the folder, not delete everything in it. Many "newbies" will do exactly what you said, and become angry and frustrated when it fails--and they've irrevocably deleted all their repository sources.